# Parameter passed from WebView to Activity

Tags: android, webview

I have to call web page from `WebView` to `Activity`.This is a two way communication which I want to achieve between an `Activity` and a page loaded in `WebView`.

**Edit**

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
     @Override 
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 
          if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) { 
             return false; 
          }
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));                          
          startActivity(intent); return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: Give me sample code JaiSoni.

Comment: private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
                return false;
            }Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }}

Comment: You can find sample code on Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the WebViewCLient (example from tutorial):

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
        // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Thomas didn't called this method shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Answer (score 0):

Have a look: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Just create an activity with a webview inside and load the URL.

Comment: How to launcher another activity from webview,